# How to use Promise.all with if statement init

Tags: javascript, node.js

For last few hours I am trying to make condition inside Promise.all to read images if there is a path for it or to pass a specific value if there is not.
When I use my code results that I get in next .then part is undefined. I checked the values that I am passing, they are not undefined. What can cause the problem?
Here is my code:

```
readPostImages: (rows) => {
  return Promise.all(
    rows.map((value) => {
      if (value.firstImage != "null") {
        return fs.promises.readFile(value.firstImage, {
          encoding: "base64",
        });
      } else {
        return Promise.resolve("null");
      }
    })
  );
},
```

And here is my App.js that return undefined:

```
  .then((result) => {
    postModules.readPostImages(result);
  })
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
    // return postModules.addImagesToData(rows, result);
  })
```

Comment: `return postModules.readPostImages(result);`?

Comment: Or rewrite the arrow function to auto-return: `.then((result) => postModules.readPostImages(result))`

Comment: THANK YOU BIG TIME with first comment. I totally forgot about return. 8 hours of coding is to much :D